# $\nu$ is a measure if $\nu(A)=\int_A f\ d\mu$ and $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ is $\mu$-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, applications

I found a result (without proof) given as an exercise in one of my measure theory texts.It says:

**Proposition**

Let $(X,\mathcal S,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ be a measurable function,define $\nu(A)=\int_A f\ d\mu$,then $\nu$ is a measure.

First of all,I want some hints to prove this result.Next I want to know why this theorem is of so much importance,what are the applications of this result and how can I use this result in problems to construct certain measures.

Comment: Just show that it satisfies the properties required of a measure. It is useful for constructing other measures such as probability measure with density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For countable additivity of disjoint measurable sets $\{E_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, let $$g_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f\cdot\mathbf{1}_{E_{i}}$$.

Then $g_{n}\uparrow\uparrow f\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i}}$ and are non-negative measurable functions

So $$\nu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i})=\int_{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i}}f\,d\mu=\int_{X}f\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i}}\,d\mu$$

$$\int_{X}f\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i}}\,d\mu=\int_{X}\lim_{n\to\infty}g_{n}\,d\mu$$
(By Monotone Convergence theorem)
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}g_{n}\,d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{E_{i}}f\,d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\nu(E_{i})$$.

To provide a motivation for this theorem, recall the definition of a probability density function. That is consider $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$

As random variables are measurable functions , you have $X^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{F}\,\forall\,A\in\mathcal{S} $

Then for a random variable $X$ with pdf $f$, you have $\mathbb{P}(\omega\in\Omega\,,X(\omega)\in A)=\int_{A}f\,d\lambda$.
That is you integrate over set to get the probability measure of "event" that the random variable takes values in that set. For more info look at the Radon Nikodym Theorem (Royden page 382) .

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable and $f$ a pdf, $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ not $\Omega$, so it should be integrate with respect to the Lebesgue measure, not $\mathbb P$.

Comment: oops, lol . I'll edit it

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, we have $\nu(\varnothing) = 0,$ and $\nu(A) \ge 0$ for all $A \in \mathcal S$. Now consider a countable collection $(A_n)_n$ of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathcal S$. We have
$$\nu\left(\bigcup_{n}A_n\right) = \int_{\bigcup_{n}A_n} fd\mu = \int_{A_n} \sum_n f \boldsymbol 1_{A_n} d\mu,$$
where $\boldsymbol 1_{A_n}$ is the characteristic function of the set $A_n$. Now to finish the argument, try to show that you can switch $\int$ and $\sum$ and then conclude.

This kind of measure is widely used in probability theory and is the basis of the Radon-Nykodym theorem:

> The Radon–Nikodym theorem involves a measurable space $(X,\mathcal S )$ on which two $\sigma$-finite measures are defined, $\mu $  and $\nu .$ It states that, if $\nu \ll \mu$ (that is, $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $\nu(A) = 0$), then there exists a $\mathcal S$-measurable function $ f:X\to [0,\infty )$, such that for any measurable set $A\subseteq X$,
> $$\nu (A)=\int _{A}f\,d\mu.$$

Consider for example $(\Omega, \mathcal S, \mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ a random variable (i.e. a measurable function). Now consider the [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) $\mathbb P_X$ (called the *distribution of the random variable*), which is a probability measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal M)$ (where $\mathcal M$ is the set of Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$), defined by
$$\mathbb P_X(A) = \mathbb P(\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in A\}), \quad \forall A \in \mathcal M.$$
Note that we clearly have $\mathbb P_X \ll \mathbb \lambda$, the Lebesgue-measure on $\mathbb R$, because $X$ is a measurable function. Therefore, by Radon-Nykodym, there exists $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb [0,\infty)$ such that
$$\mathbb P_X(A) = \int_A f d\lambda.$$

For example, for the normal distribution we have
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x - m)^2}{2\sigma}}.$$
This allows us to compute probabilities very easily.

Comment: Your answer is much more detailed. (+1)

Comment: @Falcon How come we "clearly have $\mathbb{P}_X \ll \lambda$"? I don't think measurability of $X$ is sufficient for this; we would need some form of [Luzin N property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin_N_property) for this. Or am I missing something?